# How can I return a dependent type from templated class method?

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef

Let's say I have a class based on a template `ThingType`.  In the header, I use this to `typedef` a dependent type `VectorThingType`.  I'd like to return this from a method `GetVectorOfThings()`.  If I set `VectorThingType` as the return type, I get a `Does not name a type` error, as the type wasn't defined in this scope.  Is there any way to do this without duplicating the code in the `typedef`?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template< typename ThingType >
class Thing
{
public:

 ThingType aThing;
 typedef std::vector< ThingType > VectorThingType;
 VectorThingType GetVectorOfThings();

Thing(){};
~Thing(){};

};

template< typename ThingType >
//VectorThingType // Does not name a type 
std::vector< ThingType > // Duplication of code from typedef
Thing< ThingType >
::GetVectorOfThings() {
  VectorThingType v;
  v.push_back(this->aThing);
  v.push_back(this->aThing);
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template< typename ThingType >
auto // <-- defer description of type until...
Thing< ThingType >
::GetVectorOfThings()
-> VectorThingType // <-- we are now in the context of Thing< ThingType >
{
  VectorThingType v;
  v.push_back(this->aThing);
  v.push_back(this->aThing);
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just came across another answer to this question, which doesn't involve c++11.

```
template< typename ThingType >
typename Thing< ThingType >::VectorThingType
Thing< ThingType >
::GetVectorOfThings()
{
  VectorThingType v;
  v.push_back(this->aThing);
  v.push_back(this->aThing);
  return v;
}
```

Basically involves assuring the compiler that you are, in fact, dealing with a type via `typename` and then properly scoping the type using `Thing< ThingType >::`.  Could be useful if you are stuck with c++03 for some reason.